# How to set name of the column using union

Tags: mysql, sql

I making a SQL statement using union all as the following image:

[image]

But the name of the column is the first name used in SQL query. How make this SQL statement without this my error?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `as` to make an alias name. You already do it with the `count()` column too but did not use `as` which is optional.

```
select 'abertos' as some_name, count(fk_id_status) ....
```

BTW you only need to do it for the first query in the `union`